# Replacing with values of list

Tags: replacement

It is a really simple question, but I'm a bit stuck. I have a matrix

```
J = ( {
    {e - a y - 2 x e, -a x},
    {b e y, b e x - 1 - 2 y}
   } );
```

and a list of pairs

```
listS = {{0, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, 
    0}, {(e + a)/(e (1 + b a)), (e b - 1)/(
    b a + 1)}};
```

And I want to replace (x,y) in J by values of listS and to get a list of four matrix.
The way I do it:

```
  J /. {x -> listS[[All, 1]], y -> listS[[All, 2]]}
  J /. {x,y}-> listS
```

doesn't satisfy me, because in first case I get the list of four elements with the same matrix indexes in each list element, but in the second case it replace  nothing at all.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output in this case?

Comment: Do you by any chance want `J /. (Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ listS)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your first approach is that it directly replaces `x` (and `y`) by a list.  It seems like you rather want each of `x` and `y` replaced by a single value, and to return a list of such results.  The way to do this is by supplying [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) with a list of lists of replacement rules, e.g.,

```
x /. {{x->1},{x->2},{x->3}}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

In your case, you can achieve this using [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)(`/@`) :

```
Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ listS
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> -1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> (a + e)/((1 + a b) e), y -> (-1 + b e)/(1 + a b)}}
> ```

and then perform the replacement:

```
J /. (Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ listS)
```

A nice way to view the output is

```
MatrixForm /@ %
```

> [image: MatrixForm/@%]

Answer (score 3):

Does this give the output you seek?
    f[i_] := J /. {x -> listS[[i, 1]], y -> listS[[i, 2]]};
    Table[f[i], {i, Length[listS]}]

Comment: It solves my problem too, but the solution of [jjc385](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11035/jjc385) does the same and is shorter.